# How can I find the critical points of a graph in Graphing Calculator 3D?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, graphing-functions

I would like to get a visual representation of the critical points of any graph in Graphing Calculator 3D. For example, after I plot the graph of $f(x,y)=y^3 + 3x^2 y - 6x^2 - 6y^2 + 2$, how can I get the Graphing Calculator to pinpoint the critical points? The critical points of this graph are obvious, but if there were a complex graph, it would be convenient if I can get the graph to pinpoint the critical points.

Comment: Can you make your calculator compute and plot the zeros of the gradient?

Comment: What 3D Graphing Calculator are you using? Are you talking about an online one?